# Duplicate Entry error when make pull request in github

Tags: c#, github, gitlab, winui

I am facing the below Error's when make a pull request on github.

GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE : error : PRI175: 0x80073b0f - Processing Resources failed with error: Duplicate Entry. [C:\workspace\ES\samplebrowser-winui\samplebrowser-winui\calendar\oraganization.calendardemos.winui_lib_net50.csproj]
GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE : error : PRI222: 0x80073b0f - Unspecified error occurred. [C:\workspace\ES\samplebrowser-winui\samplebrowser-winui\calendar\organization.calendardemos.winui_lib_net50.csproj]

When the above Error's appear in Gitlab. We could resolve it by made a rebuild on the last commit of that corresponding source (which means calendar, calculator etc..).

But, In git hub we couldn't resolve it by this way. Please anyone help me out to resolve it